# iframe in javascript - height can't change on mobile device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have this script code.The problem is no matter what value I define for the height in "var Mobile" , when viewed on mobile device it always remain same small height. On desktop it is ok and change height corresponging to its value.

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

var Mobile ='<iframe src="mypics/pic1mobile.jpg" width="550" height="315"></iframe>';

var Desktop = '<iframe src="mypics/pic1desktop.jpg" width="770" height="480"></iframe>';

if (screen.width < 860)
{document.write (Mobile)}
else
{document.write (Desktop)}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
if (screen.width < 860)
```

with

```
if( window.innerWidth < 860 ) {...}
```

Comment: height on mobile is not changing again

Comment: I guess that renders `height="315"` if you need bigger height, just increase that number,, like 480?

Comment: That what I mean I may enter height="900" but its not changing on mobile. On desktop is changing but on mobile not no matter what value I define

Comment: this code is OK! then look for the error somewhere else,, cache, server errors or something else

Comment: Tested on other server but same story. Perhaps I should add some container for mobile? I am missing something here. Any help ?

Comment: no you are not missing anything here, that should work. if this page is available on internet, then share URL so I can take a look, if not,, I don't know anything more that you could do..